# Static Files not working after few days

Tags: python, django

Static files - bootstrap.min.css and the js files - worked last week and today they are not!
I am using *Django 1.11* on *Python 3*.

My static files are stored in - `final/static` folder. `Final` is the name of my project, ie. it is stored in the roor

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

// End
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}QUIZ{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block x_css %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
```

Still, the css and js won't work to give a very plain and undesirable look.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Yeah- GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1670 (same for css and jquery)

Comment: Remove the space after static'/css/boot.....

Comment: did you changed anything in the css file or settings file?

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 8: 'static'css/bootstrap.min.css''. - When I removed the space between.

Comment: Can you add a picture or create a tree of your project structure?

Comment: Na, the settings file and css file are same

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT designates the directory where the collectstatic management command stores static files. You want the settings:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: `The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting` - Why can't I keep them same? What should I change now? (Though removing STATIC_ROOT statement is giving me desired results.

Comment: The management command 'python manage.py collecstatic' looks at your your STATICFILES_DIRS and copies all files contained in those directories and stores them in the directory indicated by STATIC_ROOT.  The reason you can't have root in dirs is because collecstatic would run forever because it would be looking to import files from the same place it is storing files. You probably don't really need STATIC_ROOT right now. It's useful in production when you need to configure something like nginx to serve your static files. If it requires you to set the root,  just do /www/static or something.